# What are some advanced portfolio rebalancing strategies?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio

Want to write some portfolio rebalancing code but have found only simple portfolio rebalancer strategies like calendar and threshold. I want to rebalance a portfolio with different asset groups (EQ, FI, mutual funds etc.). Are there any insightful papers or books out there that delve into some more complex portfolio rebalancing methods?

Comment: Kritzman wrote an article in 2007 that said the Markowitz van Dijk heuristic works well. It seemed interesting but I did not fully understand how the method works. As you said most of these methods are quite simple. I have implemented Daryanani rebalancing which is a simple threshold method that seems good enough to use. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will look into these methods.